# Does site_prism allow using other selectors than CSS?

Tags: ruby, capybara, site-prism

I'm researching gems that allow me to use Page Object Pattern along Capybara. I found out site_prism and looks very promising.

My question is, is there a way to define elements with selectors other than css? Like Xpath, Dom, maybe just the id's of the elements, etc.

Thanks and Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** It is possible, as of SitePrism 2.1 to use XPath expressions to find elements and sections, as well as CSS selectors.

=====

CSS only at the moment. I may change that in the future though.

Comment: Hi, am using SitePrism 2.6, but still can not use XPath to get child elements of a root elements or child elements of elements within section. I getting an error `Cannot use xpath locator strategy from an element. It can only be used from on the root element.`

Comment: @Nat Ritmeyer - I want to connect with you. Need help on SitePrism stuff. How can i get your attention for my Questions in stackoverflow.com?

Comment: @NatRitmeyer Just emailed you... Thanks