# Can you find elements by id,title,link etc through site-prism or only by css selectors?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, pageobjects, site-prism

By using site-prism gem for integration testing, can I find page elements by referring to id or title or link or xpath or are they searchable only through css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**:
It is possible, as of SitePrism 2.1 to use XPath expressions to find elements and sections, as well as CSS selectors.

====

You can only use CSS selectors, but using CSS you can still find elements by id, class, name, title, etc.

If you want to find an element by id:

`#the_id`

If you want to find an element by class:

`.the_class`

If you want to find an element by title:

`div[title='the_title']`

So, not exactly what you want, but you can get close.

Regarding XPath, see here: [Does site_prism allow using other selectors than CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293386/does-site-prism-allow-using-other-selectors-than-css)

**Update**

To find a link whose name property is 'bob':

`a[name='bob']`

To find a button whose id is 'fred':

`button#fred`

Comment: Thank You. What about finding a link or a button and performing actions (like click) on them?

Comment: Finding any element type (link/button/etc) using a CSS selector is trivial. CSS selectors are quite easy to learn. Here's a great resource: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Comment: Hi Nat. One more question. How to define images on pages? Like when i have something like this. <img class="classname" src="path">

Comment: I just did. Sorry it wasn't clear to me what that does and how it's useful.

Comment: Can i select a link by text using site-prism?